# Why Qml Popup modality is ignored?

Tags: qt, qml

I have an issue with Popup (default qml class) not being modal, despite `modality` set to `true` and `closePolicy` to `NoAutoClose`.

The problem occurs when I open the Popup by clicking a standard qml button. After opening Popup, a lengthy operation is performed, then Popup is closed.

When operation is running, whole application and the Popup itself reacts to mouse clicks. But it doesn't close the Popup. Instead it somehow clicks the button, that opened the Popup again. That shouldn't happen since my Popup is modal.

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Window 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4

ApplicationWindow {
    id: main_window

    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 500

    Item {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Popup {
            id: blockingPopup

            width: 300
            height: 50
            modal: true
            focus: true
            closePolicy: Popup.NoAutoClose
        }

        Button {
            text: "Btn"
            onClicked: {
                console.log("clicked")
                blockingPopup.open();
                cppModel.lengthyOperation()
                blockingPopup.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To summarize it again: the button is somehow clicked when I click outside (or even inside) the modal Popup when it is displayed and the operation is running.

Qt 5.12.0, Linux Mint 19.2

Comment: Can you make your code something that reproduces the problem but other people can run? For instance, it would help to know which version of Qt, what imports you are doing and what type of top level window this Item is being displayed in.

Comment: Updated the post, thx for response

Comment: Thanks - when I run that code in Qt 5.15.2, I'm not seeing the behavior you are describing.

Comment: Appreciated, as I expected, it's probably something environment specific

Comment: Your example code is not runnable. I don't have access to whatever cppModel.lengthyOperation() is doing. I created a simple example at https://gist.github.com/James-Hudson3010/deddde27b5275e48764448486495a611 but was unable to reproduce your issue. If you can reproduce it (or not) with this example code, that would be of interest. The problem could be with your lengthyOperation() function...could that code be interacting with your QML?

Comment: Thanks, James. No, your example does not produce problem. Unfortunately, I cannot post lengthyOperation() function code, as it is pretty complex. However, I can say, that my function works with criticall sections and ends with QCoreApplication::processEvents()

Comment: Does anyone know how to find the source of the button click? Like sender() in cpp. That could help me to find the cause of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in QCoreApplication::processEvents() that was in my cpp model function. It was causing clicks on a modal popup to be registered as clicks on button.